# how to pass my click message to the function in angular

Tags: angular

I need to pass to my function a parameter according to which button is clicked :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="btnClicked('approved')">Approve</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="btnClicked('cancel')">Approve</button>
```

then in my ts file i want to get create a function call it btnClicked:

```
 btnClicked(e){
 ///do somthing based on the e value
      }
```

how can i do that?

Comment: looks like everything is ok.  e parameter in btnClicked will be 'approved' or 'cancel'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it in right way,

You can access the parameter 'e' as it is,

```
btnClicked(e){
 if(e==="approved"){
   console.log("success");
 } 
}
```

Comment: It should not, check the sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2zyp7m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Extending @Sajeetharan's answer, do type check and returning Default message is good idea alaways.